# spark sql throws non-intuitve exception for when method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The exception I get is the following:
Invalid number of arguments for function when. Expected: 2; Found: 2; line 5 pos 3

This is clearly weird given that Expected is 2 and found is 2 so how is it that number of arguments is wrong then ?

I do use custom catalyst expressions that I have implemented and I have properly registered them with the context.

The sql query is

```
spark
    .sql(
        s"""
           |select
           |  ends_with_normalised(first(text), first(search_term)) as result,
           |  ends_with_udf(
           |    when(not(text is null), concat_ws("_", tokenize(first(text)))),
           |    when(not(search_term is null), concat_ws("_", tokenize(first(search_term))))
           |  ) as expected
           |from df_table
           |group by id
           |""".stripMargin
    )
```

Before you tell me that tokenize and ends_with_normalised are not defined in spark sql, I am aware of this, these are methods that I have implemented by extending Expression from org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst and are properly registered.

The logic behind the query is fairly non-sensical it is solely used for testing purpose where I try to verify that CodeGen works for my expression therefore I force WholeStageCodeGen by doing a group by.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was pretty stupid, I tried calling when in functional manner inside sql statement where I should have used "case when" style of call.

Also I had a relation issue where I did not wrap "text" and "search_term" in not expression in first which would also cause Analysis exception.

Here is a working example:

```
spark
    .sql(
        s"""
           |select
           |  ends_with_normalised(first(text), first(search_term)) as result,
           |  ends_with_udf(
           |    case when not(first(text) is null) then concat_ws("_", tokenize(first(text))) end,
           |    case when not(first(search_term) is null) then concat_ws("_", tokenize(first(search_term))) end
           |  ) as expected
           |from df_table
           |group by id
           |""".stripMargin
    )
```